# How to send SCSI USB commands in C# to a mass storage device (camera) connected to Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows IoT?

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to create a C# Universal Windows app to run on Windows IoT running on Raspberry Pi 3 and the app communicates with mass storage devices connected via USB ports. I want to send USB commands which I used to do in desktop apps by opening a SafeFileHandler and then writing commands. Is this at all possible in Universal Windows apps world?

I would also like to run a format command on that USB mass storage device from my app. This needs admin privileges when running in a desktop app. Is there a way to run apps on Windows IoT as admins? or does it work like that out of the box?

Would really appreciate any help or direction as I've been struggling with this for days now. Thanks.

Comment: Once, I used [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html)  to send SCSI commands to a usb stick to read boot sector.

Comment: @L.B thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Have you used this library in a Universal Windows app running on Windows IoT? I'm just asking as I know that this framework has a lot of limitations. Thanks

Comment: No I used in a winform app

Comment: Have you tried [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess)?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT thanks for the reply. Yes I have seen this but it says it only works with these 2 specific devices (The OSR USB FX2 learning kit and The SuperMUTT device). How can I edit this project to make it work with a generic USB mass storage device like a mounted camera SD card or a thumb drive? I think I read somewhere that this sample cannot be used to control usb mass storage devices. Is this true?

Comment: You can set your device VID and PID in Package.appxmanifest and SampleConfiguration.cs and try to find your device. For more information, you can reference ["Windows Store app for a USB device"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn303355).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I tried this but didn't have much luck. I tried setting these values in appxmanifest:
<Device Id="vidpid:4255 1000">
<Function Type="classId:05 * *" />
</Device>
and the following values in a new class called CameraUSB in the sample configuration.cs: 
public const UInt16 DeviceVid = 0x4255;
public const UInt16 DevicePid = 0x1000;
I got the VID and PID from libusb tool. I'm not sure how to set the Function Type value in the appxmanifest file. Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303351(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT yes I saw this article and I tried using classId 05 * * thinking this is used for physical device but it didn't detect my device. Can you please let me know what parameter is used to designate a standard USB storage device? Thanks.

Comment: You can find in that article: Mass storage class (0x08) but it looks like not supported.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT so does this mean I can't use this sample with mass storage devices? or I can't use Universal Windows apps to communicate with mass storage devices at all? Thanks

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Hi sorry to bother you again, but is there any other way to do this? Is there any technique used to using SafeFileHandler in UWP app or an alternative to that? Thanks.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Hi this has been a couple of months now. Any updates on this? is this still not possible in UWP app? Thanks alot.